# Компилятор javac - статический компилятор?

Tags: java, jit, javac

Цитата из книги "Java. Новое поколение разработки":

> "В техническом отношении с точки зрения теории компиляции байт-код —
>   это действительно своеобразный промежуточный язык (intermediate
>   language), а не настоящий машинный код. Это означает, что процесс
>   преобразования исходного кода Java в байт-код не является компиляцией
>   в том смысле, в каком она понимается в языках C и С++. В свою очередь,
>   javac не назовешь таким же компилятором, как gcc. В сущности, это
>   генератор файлов классов для обработки исходного кода Java. Настоящим
>   компилятором в экосистеме Java является динамический компилятор
>   (JIT)".

Правильно ли я понимаю, что, в то время как JIT - динамический компилятор, javac - статический компилятор?

Comment: в java нет статической компиляции.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Javac** не является статическим компилятором. Потому, что он генерирует байт код, который уже в процессе выполнения программы будет *динамически компилироваться* в машинный код, или *интерпретироваться*.

Но в **java 9** появится [возможность](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/295) генерировать машинный код до запуска программы.

Comment: А вот эта вот Ahead-Of-Time компиляция, которая появится в java 9, будет полноценной статической компиляцией, так?

Comment: @Ksenia именно так. будет генерироваться сразу нативный код